# PostgreSQL GIN index for nearest neighbours?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

Let's say I have a set of docs. Each doc is an unordered bag of strings

```
{a, b, b, d}, {a, b}, {j, k, d, a}, ....
```

Is it possible to use GIN to find all docs that are similar to the doc X? As a **similarity - cosine or euclidean distance** is used.

I know PostgreSQL provides trigram search. It's very similar to what I want. But without trigram. I want to use my own vectors.

Something like `SELECT * from DOCS where content like {a, b, c}`.

```
INSERT INTO docs (content) VALUES ({i, j, k})
INSERT INTO docs (content) VALUES ({a})
INSERT INTO docs (content) VALUES ({b, c})
...

-- Somehow build GIN index over the docs.content field

SELECT * FROM docs WHERE content LIKE {a, b, c}
```

Is it possible to do something like that with GIN?

If it helps - a bag of numbers could be used instead of bag of strings.

Comment: Actually, now that I read your question more carefully (obviously, _after_ replying) I am not 100% sure about what you want to do... can you specify?

Comment: `As a similarity measure pretty much anything could be used - cosine, euclidean, etc.` That makes the question completely random. Please specify the kind of similarity you need.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks for reply, **similarity - cosine or euclidean distance**.

Comment: @giorgiga thanks for reply, **similarity - cosine or euclidean distance**.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin the reason I was asking is because full-text search support in postgres (which does make use of GIN/GIST) could be what you are looking for, but I can't really tell since you don't explain what you are implementing. In case, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html (and then §12.9 about indexes)

Answer (score 1):

You can use GIN indexes to check if an array *contains* another array:

```
create table docs(content text[]);

insert into docs values ('{a,b}'),('{a,b,c}'),('{a,b,c,d}'), ('{a,c,d}'),('{a,b,d}');

create index on docs using gin(content);

select content from docs where content @> '{b,c}'; -- this can use the index
```

### Caveat emptor!

The `@>` operator may not work the way one expects: it treats arrays a bit like they were sets...

```
select '{a}'  ::text[] @> '{a,a}'::text[]; -- true!
select '{a,b}'::text[] @> '{b,a}'::text[]; -- true!
```

### Relevant doc topics

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-array.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/gin-builtin-opclasses.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createindex.html